# I am trying to connect product sale records to the appropriate purchase record in SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a transaction table with both purchases and sales. Purchase datetime, quantity, unit cost as well as the corresponding Sales data.
I can separate the transactions with queries no problem there. What I need to do is determine which purchase order supplied the product sold and the difference in purchase and sale rate.

```
transDate     | transType     | Product | transQty | transRate 
12/5/20       | purchase      | pencils | 124      | $5.12     
12/6/20       | sale          | pencils | 32       | $6.12     
12/7/20       | sale          | pencils | 67       | $6.21     
12/8/20       | purchase      | pencils | 65       | $4.85     
12/10/20      | sale          | pencils | 44       | $6.32     
12/11/20      | purchase      | pencils | 14       | $6.11
```

The purchase on 12/5 covers the sales on 12/6, 12/7, and a portion of the sale in 12/10 with the purchase on 12/8 covering the remainder of 12/10.

Reorganized tables

```
tblPurchaseRecords
pID | transDate | Product | pQty | pTransRate | pRemaining
1   | 12/5/20   | pencils | 124  | $5.12     | 124
2   | 12/8/20   | pencils | 65   | $4.85     | 65
3   | 12/11/20  | pencils | 14   | $6.11     | 14

tblSaleRecords
sID | transDate | Product | sQty | sTransRate | sRemaining
1   | 12/6/20   | pencils | 32   | $6.12     | 32
2   | 12/7/20   | pencils | 67   | $6.21     | 67
3   | 12/10/20  | pencils | 44   | $6.32     | 44
```

New table

```
tblProfitLoss
pID | sID | plQty | plRate | plValue
```

tblProfitLoss is a many-to-many table with sID and pID forming the primary key.
plQty is the MIN(pRemaining, sRemaining). This value is subtracted from both pRemaining and sRemaining. One or both of the two values will be reduced to 0, advancing the respective index(es) by 1.
Resulting in this:

```
tblPurchaseRecords
pID | transDate | Product | pQty | pTransRate | pRemaining
1   | 12/5/20   | pencils | 124  | $5.12     | 0
+pID | sID | plQty | plRate | plValue
 1   | 1   | 32    | $1.00  | $32.00
 1   | 2   | 67    | $1.09  | $73.03
 1   | 3   | 25    | $1.20  | $30
2   | 12/8/20   | pencils | 65   | $4.85     | 46
+pID | sID | plQty | plRate | plValue
 2   | 3   | 19    | $1.47  | $27.93
3   | 12/11/20  | pencils | 14   | $6.11     | 14

tblSaleRecords
sID | transDate | Product | sQty | sTransRate | sRemaining
1   | 12/6/20   | pencils | 32   | $6.12     | 0
+pID | sID | plQty | plRate | plValue
 1   | 1   | 32    | $1.00  | $32.00
2   | 12/7/20   | pencils | 67   | $6.21     | 0
+pID | sID | plQty | plRate | plValue
 1   | 2   | 67    | $1.09  | $73.03
3   | 12/10/20  | pencils | 44   | $6.32     | 0
+pID | sID | plQty | plRate | plValue
 1   | 3   | 25    | $1.20  | $30
 2   | 3   | 19    | $1.47  | $27.93
```

I can do this with VBA but I was hoping to learn how to do it with SQL.

Comment: If you left join the tblPurchaseRecords table to the tblProfitLoss table by pId, does that get you the close desired effect? Not sure how to do the subtraction of pRemaining and sRemaining, but I'd say that's an application concern and not a database concern.

Comment: If you want to calculate profit/loss individually for each record then you must have purchase ID in `tblSaleRecords` records.

Comment: @KyleUP The problem I have is populating tblProfitLoss. The original list already exists, tblPurchasecords and tblSaleRecords can be recreated with a query. 

I am thinking that using a query to select all tblProfitLoss records with an sID = to the current tblSaleRecord.sID then compare the sum of plQty with sQty of the current tblSaleRecord. 
If they are equal then advance to the next record in tblSaleRecords (increment a stored value).
If they are not equal then advance to the next record intblPurchaseRecords. Create a new tblProfitLoss record with pID sID and the lessor qty. Do again.

Comment: @Harun24HR A single Purchase may cover several Sales. It is also possible that what remains of one Purchase does not cover the current Sale so the Remainder of that Sale has to be covered by the Next Purchase. tblProfitLoss has both pID and sID to join the two currently unrelated tables.